# How to type a computed property in the new composition API?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I'm playing along with the new Vue.js plugin for using composition API and TypeScript and there is something I'm not understanding.

How am I supposed to type computed properties?

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { ref, computed, Ref } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default Vue.extend({
  setup(props, context) {

    const movieName:Ref<string> = ref('Relatos Salvajes')
    const country:Ref<string> = ref('Argentina')

    const nameAndCountry = computed(() => `The movie name is ${movieName.value} from ${country.value}`);

    return { movieName, country, nameAndCountry }
  }
})
```

In this simple example I'm declaring two refs and a computed property to join both. VSC is telling me that computed properties are returning `ReadOnly` type... But I can't make it work.

Comment: *But I can't make it work* - what exactly? From your code I'd expect the type to be inferred correctly.

Comment: I mean, what type should I add to `nameAndCountry` const for it to be properly typed. Is it something that should we do in a TS app with computed values?

Comment: I expect it to be something like Ref<ReadOnly<string>>. You don’t need to add a type here, it’s inferred. Also no need for refs, they are unambiguously inferred as strings. Make sure TS is in strict mode so you’ll be warned when types are skipped where they are required.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There are two different types for that.

If your computed prop is readonly:

```
const nameAndCountry: ComputedRef<string> = computed((): string => `The movie name is ${movieName.value} from ${country.value}`);
```

if it has a setter method:

```
const nameAndCountry: WritableComputedRef<string> = computed({
  get(): string {
    return 'somestring'
  },
  set(newValue: string): void {
    // set something
  },
});
```

Comment: Where is the documentation for this? When I look up how to do setters on computed properties for the composition API I do not see the above instructions https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#computed-setter

Comment: This answer and this github comment: https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/issues/171#issuecomment-895616971 are the only two places I could find "documentation" on computed getter and setter with composition API.

Comment: The documentation includes a hint that "Computed values will automatically infer the type from returned value"
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#typing-computed

Comment: this answer throws errors

Comment: don't forget to: import { ComputedRef } from 'vue'

Answer (score 7):

I believe you should go with using generics:

```
const movieName = ref<string>("Relatos Salvajes")
const country = ref<string>("Argentina")

const nameAndCountry = computed<string>(
  () => `The movie name is ${movieName.value} from ${country.value}`
)
```

https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-computed

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I like it more than accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript in many cases will automatically infer the type. So let's say we have the following variable:

```
const movie = ref('relatos salvajes')
```

If you now move the mouse over `movie` you'll see that TS infers that is a `string` and if you try to change the value to for example a number it will throw an error.

[image]

So, we don't need to explicitly write the type of most `ref()` constants. TypeScript will protect as anyways. Look at the following error:

[image]

Okay, now let's see something interesting. If you have a `string` which you only want it to be two specific `strings`, then we can use generics like so:

```
const movies = ref<'titanic'|'forest gump'>('titanic')
```

If we then try to set the value of movies to for example `'relatos salvajes'` TS will throw an error.

An example for numbers:

```
const movies = ref<0|10|20>(0)
```

**Generics in computed properties**

When using `computed()`, types are also automatically infer, but if you would like to add specific interfaces or types then you can use generics the same way you would do it with `ref()`

```
interface User{
    uid: string,
    username: string,
    age: number
}

const userData = computed<User>(() => store.state.user)
```

You can [find more info here](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html)